# Creating field group in installation profile

Tags: drupal, installation, drupal-7, field

In Drupal I would like my attachment fields to be in a vertical tab. I have made some progress. I have the following code:

```
$field_group = new stdClass();
$field_group->disabled = FALSE; 
$field_group->api_version = 1;
$field_group->identifier = 'group_test|node|foo|form';
$field_group->group_name = 'group_test';
$field_group->entity_type = 'node';
$field_group->bundle = 'foo';
$field_group->mode = 'form';
$field_group->parent_name = '';
$field_group->data = array(
    'label' => 'Test group',
    'weight' => '43',
    'children' => array(),
    'format_type' => 'tab',
    'format_settings' => array(
        'formatter' => 'closed',
        'instance_settings' => array(
            'description' => '',
            'classes' => 'group-test field-group-tab',
            'required_fields' => 1,
        ),
    ),
);

field_group_group_save($field_group);
```

This adds a field group in Drupal, the only problem now is that the data value(array with settings) is not imported. So I have a field group without data.

For your knowledge I got part of this code using 'ctools bulk exporter'.

Any ideas on how I can edit the code so my settings are also imported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D7, I don't have a 'data' member in my $field_group object. Each of the elements under your 'data' member should be directly under the field_group. In a little different format (to save myself some typing), I do this:

```
$group = (object) array(
  'identifier' => 'group_userprofile_vendor2|user|user|form',
  'group_name' => 'group_userprofile_vendor2',
  'entity_type' => 'user',
  'bundle' => 'user',
  'mode' => 'form',
  'label' => 'Vendor Info',
  'children' => array(),
  'weight' => '300',
  'format_type' => 'tab',
  'format_settings' => array(
    'formatter' => 'closed',
    'instance_settings' => array(
      'description' => '',
      'classes' => '',
      'required_fields' => 1,
    ),
  ),
);
field_group_group_save($group);
```

Also, as noted [here](https://drupal.org/node/1893460), if you've already added the group once, it throws an error if you try to do it again. I had actually tested the code above, then deleted the group via the UI, but it still throw an error when I tried it again. I finally had to change the group_name (thus the '2' after the name above) to get it to run again. So you might want to watch that during debugging.